# JQuery откидывает вверх

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Есть контейнер, который должен появляться по щелчку на кнопку. Написал такой код и вроде бы всё отлично, всё работает, но одно "Но". При щелчке откидывает на вверх страницы. Это вообще законно?

```
 $('.price .table__container').hide();
    $(".btn-green").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".table__container").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass("activeBtn");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в функцию, вызываемую по клику, такой код:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Таким образом стандартное действие не будет вызвано.

Answer (score 2):

Могу поспорить, что `.btn-green` - это ссылка . При нажатии оно добавляет [якорь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya) `#` или обновляет страницу. Что бы этого не происходило нужно добавить в конец функции `return false`. *[return false](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action)* отключает другие действия, которые идут после нажатия на кнопку:

```
$('.price .table__container').hide();
$(".btn-green").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".table__container").slideToggle(500);
  $(this).toggleClass("activeBtn");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: @Данил, я обновил ответ и всё расписал